# How are $x$ and $\ln(\ln(x))$ related?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

It is known that the graphs of the functions $e^x$ and $\ln(x)$ are reflections of each other about the line $y = x$. Are the functions $e^{\ln(x)}$ i.e. $x$ and $\ln(\ln(x))$ also symmetric in some similar way? Are they reflections of each other about some nice function(of course not $y = x$).

Comment: Well, $e^{\ln x} = x$, so.................

Comment: It has deliberately been written in that manner, to emphasize the motivation behind the question.

Comment: @SoumilAggarwal What I mean is that the answer is pretty much trivially no, at least in whatever sense I can think of. $e^{\ln x}$ is a straight line, and $\ln(\ln x)$ is very much not.

Comment: So if $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = \ln(x)$, you're asking for the relationship between $f(g(x))$ and $g(g(x))$.  Is that right?

Comment: What I was thinking was maybe they are reflections of each other about a function that is not a straight line?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Yes, that's right.

Comment: An interesting version of the question is this: "what curve should $y = x$ be reflected through in order to produce $y = \ln(\ln(x))$?" The matter of reflecting something through a curve which isn't a line seems a bit tricky though...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Yes that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Another way to put this is that you're looking for the locus of points equidistant from the two curves, which I think should consist of the curve formed by the intersections of normal lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_1(x) = \ln(x)$ and $f_2(x) = e^x$. Then $f_1(f_2(x)) = x$ and $f_2(f_1(x))$. This relationship is the "symmetry" (intentionally in quotes) that you see between $\ln(\ln(x))$ and $e^{\ln(x)}$.

For $e^{\ln(x)}$ and $\ln(\ln(x))$, you have simply replaced $x$ with $\ln(x)$.

So, in a certain sense, $\ln(\ln(x))$ is "symmetric" to $e^{\ln(x)}$ across $\ln(x)$.

A plot shows this "symmetry":

[image]

The middle green plot is $y = \ln(x)$.

---

This same "symmetry" applies to any substitution in $x$, for example:

$f(x) = \sin(x)+2.$

Here is the graph:

[image]

You may notice that $\ln(f(x))$ lies below $f(x)$ and $e^{f(x)}$ lies above $f(x)$: this is obviously apparent from the fact that $\ln(x) < x < e^x$ for all $x$ (where $\ln(x)$ is defined, of course).

If you want to play around a bit more with these graphs with different $f$s, here is a [desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pq6daame1l) with everything set up, just change $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please elaborate on how this relationship can be justified a little more?

Comment: I will add more explanation.